# React router appending query to URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

React router seems to be appending a query to the end of my routes. The app is being served by a node server running express. I'm using the latest version of react-router "1.0.0-rc1"

Example:
`http://localhost:8080/#/users?_k=8wsy62`

Two questions

1) Why is this happening?

2) How can I stop it from appending the query to the url?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactRouter = require('react-router');
var Router = ReactRouter.Router;
var Route = ReactRouter.Route;
var Link = ReactRouter.Link;
var IndexRoute = ReactRouter.IndexRoute;

var App = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="app">
                <h1>App</h1>
                <Link to="/users">Users</Link>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var Home = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="home">
                <h2>Home</h2>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var Users = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="users">
                <h2>Users</h2>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

React.render((
    <Router>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <IndexRoute component={Home} />
            <Route path="users" component={Users} />
        </Route>
    </Router>
), document.body);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taken from this link: http://rackt.github.io/history/stable/HashHistoryCaveats.html

> HTML5 gives us the pushState method and the popstate event, but in
>   older browsers the only thing we have is the URL. So, when using hash
>   history, you'll see an extra item in your query string that looks
>   something like _k=123abc. This is a key that history uses to look up
>   persistent state data in window.sessionStorage between page loads.

You can check both the link above and this one for ideas on how to stop this if you don't like it: https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/1952#issuecomment-140401701

Comment: I changed the router history prop to `history={createBrowserHistory({queryKey: false})` to remove the extra item. Though I'm unsure if I need state data at this time.