# React router 4 appending extra query param

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

My problem is similar to [React router appending query to URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32833068/react-router-appending-query-to-url) but I'm using react router 4 with Switch and routes.In my case,How can I exclude the extra query param that appends from history ?

```
  render(){
return(
  <div>
    <Header/>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" render={(props) => (<Home passDealsToRoute ={this.dealsCallBack} {...props}/>)}/>
      <Route exact path="/mall/:id/:store_id/:deal_id" render={(props) => (<MallDetail deals ={this.deals} {...props}/>)}/>
      <Route exact path="/mall/:id/:store_id" render={(props) => (<MallDetail deals ={this.deals} {...props}/>)}/>
      <Route exact path="/mall/:id" render={(props) => (<MallDetail deals ={this.deals} {...props}/>)}/>
      <Route path="/home/:location" render={(props) => (<Home passDealsToRoute ={this.dealsCallBack} {...props}/>)} />
      <Route exact path="/about" component={About}/>
    </Switch>
    <Footer/>
  </div>
);}} export default withRouter(Root);
```

My index file

```
import React from 'react';


import {BrowserRouter,Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import Root from './components/root/root';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
const history = createBrowserHistory({queryKey: false});

class App extends React.Component {
 render() {
   return(
    <BrowserRouter history={history}>
      <Route path={"/"} component={Root}/>
    </BrowserRouter>
   );
 }
 };

 render(<App/>,window.document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Go back to your file (I guess `index.js`) where you are using `<BrowserHistory />` and add the following:

> Note that you will grab `createBrowserHistory` from "history" package not "react-router-dom" 
>   Also "queryKey: false" is the answer here .

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

const history = createBrowserHistory({queryKey: false});
//.....

<BrowserRouter history={history}>
  // Your routes here ...
</BrowserRouter >
```

Note :

You may organize your routes better by removing exact & reversing all routes since you are leveraging `<Switch />` component.

Comment: Thank you so much.I've added that but it is still passing extra query param with every api call. as &_=1505635138301 .I've added my index file.

Comment: fixed by adding cache true.Anyhow your answer helped me a lot to understand the router & history concepts of react.Thanks a ton :)

Answer (score 0):

The actual cause was not because of react router,but by the ajax api call.I solved the issue by making `'cache':true` in my ajax call.That fixed my issue.Anyhow answer posted by Abdennour was correct in case of react router.